# difference between "ifndef" and "if !defined" in C?

Tags: c, include-guards

I have seen  `#ifndef ABC` and `#if !defined (ABC)` in the same C source file.

Is there subtle difference between them? 
(If it is a matter of style, why would someone use them in the same file)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No, there's no difference between the two when used that way. The latter form (using `defined()`) is useful when the initial `#if` or one of the subsequent `#elif` conditions needs a more complex test. `#ifdef` will still work, but it might be clearer using `#if defined()` in that case. For example, if it needs to test if more than one macro is defined, or if it equals a specific value.

The variance (using  both in a file) could depend on specific subtleties in usage, as mentioned above, or just poor practice, by being inconsistent.

Answer (score 8):

In the context you gave, they are the same:  you are just checking for the existence of one macro identifier.

However, the #if  form allows you to evaluate expressions, which can be useful.